# Mathematica Lists Combining X,Y,Z Co-Ordinates

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, coordinates

I am a beginner in Mathematica. My question is: I have huge amount of x,y and z co-ordinates in separate lists named XCORD,YCORD,ZCORD and I want to combine them in one list

Example:
If the x co-oridinates list is given by `XCORD = {x1,x2,x3}`, the y co-ordinates list by`YCORD = {y1,y2,y3}` and the z co-ordinates list by `ZCORD = {z1,z2,z3}`,  I would like to have a resulting list of co-ordinates that looks like this:

```
 {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},{x3,y3,z3}}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Faz! Please note that I edited your question somewhat and removed your desperate plea. Such utterances are unnecessary here to get attention and help. Please vote-up answers you like using the vote buttons, and don't forget to accept the answer you like as the final answer using the checkmark button. You may want to wait a little for more answers to come in before doing that.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html):

```
XCORD = {x1, x2, x3};
YCORD = {y1, y2, y3};
ZCORD = {z1, z2, z3};

res = Transpose[{XCORD, YCORD, ZCORD}]

==> {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}}
```

More information about working with lists can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html), and more specific to your question, [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/RearrangingAndRestructuringLists.html).

Please note that it's better (though it's allowed) not to start any variable of your own with a uppercase letter. Using a lowercase start of your variable name means you'll never get into conflict with the thousands of built-in symbols that all start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: @acl I was cheating. With Mr.Wizard back, I thought I might run my WatchSO utility (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6505675/615464) and it helps. I had even time editing the question before working on the answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd I started flagging Mr. Wiz answers for infringing the speed limit. Hopefully he will be banned if they can catch him :)

Comment: @belisarius LOL, but it seems he's a bit out of shape lately.

Comment: @Sjoerd, yeah. I beat him to the punch earlier. Must be the "vacation;" he needs time to bring himself back up to cruising speed.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate solution using the [MapThread](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) function:

```
In[2]:= MapThread[List, {{x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}, {z1, z2, z3}}]

Out[2]= {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}}
```

For large lists, [Transpose](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) is an ordner of a magnitude faster, though:

```
In[3]:= With[{n=10^6}, x=RandomReal[1, n]; y=RandomReal[2, n]; z=RandomReal[3, n];]

In[4]:= Transpose[{x, y, z}]; // Timing

Out[4]= {0.644832, Null}

In[5]:= MapThread[List, {x, y, z}]; // Timing

Out[5]= {5.87969, Null}
```

Comment: I would definitely encourage people to become more familiar with `MapThread`, it is extremely useful in general. On the other hand, which is faster in this case: `Transpose` or `MapThread`?

Comment: thank you. I appreciate the timings, especially when there are competing options, but I was being a little facetious.